# Menor numero digitado mostra zero sempre

Tags: python

```
numero = 0
resposta = 'ok'
num_total = 0
contador = 0
maior_num = 0
menor_num = 0
tot_pares = 0
aux = 0
while (resposta == 'ok'):
    contador += 1
    numero = int(input('digite um numero: '))
    resposta = str(input('deseja continuar? '))
    num_total = num_total + numero
    qtde = contador
    media = num_total / qtde
    if numero % 2 == 0:
        tot_pares = tot_pares + numero
        media_pares = tot_pares / qtde

    if (numero > maior_num):
        maior_num = numero
        numero = aux

    if (numero < menor_num):
        menor_num = numero
        numero = aux

print('a soma ficou: %d' % num_total)
print('a quantidade de numeros digitados foi: %d' % qtde)
print('a media: %.2f' % media)
print('a media dos pares foi: %.2f' % media_pares)
print('o maior numero foi: %d' % maior_num, 'e o menor foi %d' % menor_num)
```

Comment: O `menor_num` começa em zero e continuará sendo zero a menos que você digite um número negativo.

Comment: Inicialize o menor número com um número bem alto (sys.maxsize), ou com o primeiro número digitado

Comment: Leonardo eu já fiz o procedimento de atribuir a variável "numero" para a "menor_num".

Comment: consegui alterar o código para conseguir o que pretendia, não posto pois a quantidade de caracteres excede o limite.